# Angular JS clear entire history stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have recently started working on angular JS. 
Currently i am using `$location.replace()` method, but it clears only the current state. What i want to do is to clear entire history stack of my Angular Single Page Application: Example:

I have 3 routes on my Angular SPA application : `#loginPage`, `#registerPage`, and  `#homePage.`

First my application lands on `#loginPage`, on that page after clicking register link `#registerPage` is called, **on clicking submit button on successful registration** `#homePage` is displayed. 
Now, before clicking submit button i want to let user to traverse the back path i.e. `#registerPage` to `#loginPage`.

However, After successful registration, i want to restrict user from traversing the path.

So is there any way possible i could restrict user from traversing entire history at specific point.

Comment: do you just want to avoid logged users to access some pages i.e '#registerPage' or theres another reason for you doing this?

Comment: @ElmerDantas Idea is to, save user from the trouble of filling all the details again, untill successful / failed registration and also restricting them to access the  '#registerPage'  after its work is done.

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot help with the "filling all the details again" part but, to restricting user to access a page after successful login, you can use angular `resolve` on routeProvider http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx so, you can check in `resolve` function if the user is logged in and then restrict his access to the page.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Thanks for the quick response,  details and everything getting filled, however i am unable to restrict the user from accesing the same, i am exploring the suggestion given by you. However, i was looking for more generalized solution like clearing history at specific event, So i dont have to manage it explicitly everywhere. I am expective that if <code>$location.path("/homePage").replace()</code>  can clear out the last path then there must be a way i could clear out all the traversed path at once.

Comment: Sorry for not being that helpful. You can try take a look on $routes events in the docs (i.e the `$routeChangeSuccess` has informations about the previous routes) I don't know if you can "clear" this information but I think it worthy take a look on this.